# "Network path was not found" error when Windows resumes, if remote folders are open

Tags: windows-7, networking

If there is a network drive folder open in Explorer when Windows goes to sleep / hibernate, I get "Network Error - Windows cannot access " error message. Error code is 0x80070035 and name "The network path was not found".

I assume that Windows checks accessibility of the folder immediately after resuming, before the network interface is up.

Is there a way to fix this annoying issue?

Comment: I think your assumption is correct, and I don't think there is a fix besides changing behavior to (A) close all network folders before hibernating, or (B) accept the error message and refresh the Explorer page a moment later.

Comment: I do not know any better than suspect ‘shadow copies’ of shared network resources, at work I connect to Win2008 servers and although I absolutely disabled any thumbnails of photos I edit and move around I cannot refresh the Windows 7 file explorers on my workstation without closing all of them..  I keep getting errors of thumbnail databases still in use, and seeing folders and files I already removed. This is happening in real-time, without any hibernation.